# How to access the collection result returned by var in a collection using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I've a collection stored in a variable. I need to iterate through a Iqueryable object collection using the var result value in where clause. Any suggestion would help.

```
var collection = courses.Where(r => r.deptTAG == deptTag).Select(d => d.dept_NO);  

IQueryable<courses> query = getcourses();                

if (collection != null)
 {
   query = query.Where(c => c.dept_NO == collection.????);
   shipments = query.ToList();
  }

  return shipments ;
```

Comment: What do you want to do with that collection?

Comment: I need to check if the 'dept_no' stored in 'var collection' is available in Iqueryable object collection based on dept_no. Actually I need to iterate through the Iqueryable object collection to check for the values returned by the var.

Comment: Do you want to get items which has `dept_NO` stored in `collection`?

Comment: yes. but my question is can I attain it using foreach loop or Is there better option.

Comment: Why do you need the collection? What is wrong with `shipments = getcourses().Where(r => r.deptTAG == deptTag).ToList(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `join` on two `IEnumerables`:

```
query = from q in query
    join r in collection
    on q.dept_no equals r.dept_no
    select q;
```

Comment: I can't access the dept_no field from the var collection. q.dept_no equals r.dept_no . here I don't see the dept_no prompted in intellisense.

Comment: Never trust intellisense to know everything, especially when dealing with dynamics and var.  if you type r.dept_no anyway do you see the telltale error underlining?

Comment: user1895086 - your solution worked great. I converted both my collections to  IEnumerables.

Comment: Glad to be of service!